# Find Each method how long it takes to execution till Login page in .NET? (Method execution profile)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, performancecounter

Currently I am working of a project which has 100+ projects. It is mainly web application having some schedule service as well. It is not run directly from visual studio run button instated pointing to IIS and build and access IIS url to run application. When I request URL it took me more than 3 minute for login screen to come. I want to find which was cause that much of delay. I am thinking of having some way find each method how long it takes? Please give me some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of performance profiling tools for VS, including built-in ones. And I know you're saying you don't run the project from VS, but you can still attach the VS debugger to a running W3WP.EXE to debug it.

Try ANTS Performance Profiler (there's a free trial version).